Calculation of dipole moment from gaussian
I am trying to calculate the dipole moment of water molecule using Gaussian16. The problem I face is the use of Density=Current keyword in the route section. Here is the input file and output file without density=current.
# ccsd(full)/aug-cc-pvtz scf=tight

Title Card Required

0 1
 O                  0.00000000    0.00000000    0.11694700
 H                  0.00000000    0.75644600   -0.46778800
 H                  0.00000000   -0.75644600   -0.46778800

Now, the last part of the output,
 Dipole moment (field-independent basis, Debye):
    X=             -0.0000    Y=              0.0000    Z=             -1.9803  Tot=              1.9803
 Quadrupole moment (field-independent basis, Debye-Ang):
   XX=             -7.5555   YY=             -4.2444   ZZ=             -6.2461
   XY=              0.0000   XZ=              0.0000   YZ=             -0.0000
 Traceless Quadrupole moment (field-independent basis, Debye-Ang):
   XX=             -1.5402   YY=              1.7709   ZZ=             -0.2308
   XY=              0.0000   XZ=              0.0000   YZ=             -0.0000
 Octapole moment (field-independent basis, Debye-Ang**2):
  XXX=              0.0000  YYY=             -0.0000  ZZZ=             -1.1420  XYY=             -0.0000
  XXY=              0.0000  XXZ=             -0.2547  XZZ=              0.0000  YZZ=              0.0000
  YYZ=             -1.4009  XYZ=             -0.0000
 Hexadecapole moment (field-independent basis, Debye-Ang**3):
 XXXX=             -6.7242 YYYY=             -5.9447 ZZZZ=             -7.2267 XXXY=             -0.0000
 XXXZ=             -0.0000 YYYX=             -0.0000 YYYZ=              0.0000 ZZZX=             -0.0000
 ZZZY=              0.0000 XXYY=             -2.4393 XXZZ=             -2.3744 YYZZ=             -1.8515
 XXYZ=             -0.0000 YYXZ=              0.0000 ZZXY=              0.0000
 N-N= 9.205382556144D+00 E-N=-1.990249442468D+02  KE= 7.596313910169D+01
 Symmetry A1   KE= 6.791317732063D+01
 Symmetry A2   KE= 7.201615251558D-30
 Symmetry B1   KE= 4.465944658470D+00
 Symmetry B2   KE= 3.584017122599D+00
 Unable to Open any file for archive entry.
 1\1\GINC-NODE682\SP\RCCSD-Full\Aug-CC-pVTZ\H2O1\N93349PB\03-Jun-2024\0
 \\# ccsd(full)/aug-cc-pvtz scf=tight\\Title Card Required\\0,1\O,0,0.,
 0.,0.116947\H,0,0.,0.756446,-0.467788\H,0,0.,-0.756446,-0.467788\\Vers
 ion=ES64L-G16RevC.01\State=1-A1\HF=-76.0606866\MP2=-76.3441335\MP3=-76
 .3468449\MP4D=-76.3515355\MP4DQ=-76.34733\MP4SDQ=-76.3492471\CCSD=-76.
 3487662\RMSD=3.778e-09\PG=C02V [C2(O1),SGV(H2)]\\@
 The archive entry for this job was punched.


 "ANNA, YOU MUSN'T SPEAK OF OXIDIZED MURIATIC ACID
 ANYMORE, FROM NOW ON YOU MUST SAY CHLORINE."
   -- JENS JACOB BERZELIUS, IN 1820, TO HIS COOK, WHO HAD
 COMPLAINED OF THE SMELL OF THE FLASK SHE WAS CLEANING.
 Job cpu time:       0 days  0 hours  0 minutes 12.9 seconds.
 Elapsed time:       0 days  0 hours  0 minutes  3.7 seconds.
 File lengths (MBytes):  RWF=     77 Int=      0 D2E=      0 Chk=      2 Scr=      1
 Normal termination of Gaussian 16 at Mon Jun  3 15:38:57 2024.

The total dipole moment is 1.98 D. But with Density=Current, the input is,
# ccsd(full)/aug-cc-pvtz scf=tight density=current

Title Card Required

0 1
 O                  0.00000000    0.00000000    0.11694700
 H                  0.00000000    0.75644600   -0.46778800
 H                  0.00000000   -0.75644600   -0.46778800

The output is,
 Dipole moment (field-independent basis, Debye):
    X=             -0.0000    Y=              0.0000    Z=             -1.8630  Tot=              1.8630
 Quadrupole moment (field-independent basis, Debye-Ang):
   XX=             -7.7258   YY=             -4.4030   ZZ=             -6.3996
   XY=              0.0000   XZ=              0.0000   YZ=              0.0000
 Traceless Quadrupole moment (field-independent basis, Debye-Ang):
   XX=             -1.5497   YY=              1.7731   ZZ=             -0.2235
   XY=              0.0000   XZ=              0.0000   YZ=              0.0000
 Octapole moment (field-independent basis, Debye-Ang**2):
  XXX=              0.0000  YYY=             -0.0000  ZZZ=             -0.9951  XYY=             -0.0000
  XXY=              0.0000  XXZ=             -0.2075  XZZ=              0.0000  YZZ=              0.0000
  YYZ=             -1.3177  XYZ=             -0.0000
 Hexadecapole moment (field-independent basis, Debye-Ang**3):
 XXXX=             -7.3320 YYYY=             -6.3400 ZZZZ=             -7.6866 XXXY=             -0.0000
 XXXZ=             -0.0000 YYYX=             -0.0000 YYYZ=              0.0000 ZZZX=             -0.0000
 ZZZY=             -0.0000 XXYY=             -2.6076 XXZZ=             -2.5511 YYZZ=             -2.0238
 XXYZ=             -0.0000 YYXZ=              0.0000 ZZXY=             -0.0000
 N-N= 9.205382556144D+00 E-N=-1.990258773584D+02  KE= 7.623035083531D+01
 Symmetry A1   KE= 6.800317321545D+01
 Symmetry A2   KE= 2.731934657745D-02
 Symmetry B1   KE= 4.484066046784D+00
 Symmetry B2   KE= 3.715792226490D+00
 Unable to Open any file for archive entry.
 1\1\GINC-NODE635\SP\RCCSD-Full\Aug-CC-pVTZ\H2O1\N93349PB\03-Jun-2024\0
 \\# ccsd(full)/aug-cc-pvtz scf=tight density=current\\Title Card Requi
 red\\0,1\O,0,0.,0.,0.116947\H,0,0.,0.756446,-0.467788\H,0,0.,-0.756446
 ,-0.467788\\Version=ES64L-G16RevC.01\State=1-A1\HF=-76.0606866\MP2=-76
 .3441335\MP3=-76.3468449\MP4D=-76.3515355\MP4DQ=-76.34733\MP4SDQ=-76.3
 492471\CCSD=-76.3487663\RMSD=3.778e-09\Dipole=0.,0.,-0.7329466\Quadrup
 ole=-1.1521315,1.3182869,-0.1661554,0.,0.,0.\PG=C02V [C2(O1),SGV(H2)]\
 \@
 The archive entry for this job was punched.


 ... I FELL INTO A REVERIE ... THE ATOMS WERE GAMBOLING BEFORE MY EYES
 ... I SAW HOW TWO SMALL ONES UNITED TO FORM A PAIR;
 HOW THE LARGER ONES SEIZED TWO OF THE SMALLER ONES;
 HOW STILL LARGER ONES KEPT HOLD OF THREE OR FOUR
 SMALLER ONES ... I SAW HOW THE LARGER ONES FORMED A CHAIN ...
 THIS WAS THE ORIGIN OF THE STRUCTURE THEORY.

                                   -- C.F.KEKULE VON STRADONITZ
 Job cpu time:       0 days  0 hours  5 minutes 23.8 seconds.
 Elapsed time:       0 days  0 hours  1 minutes 28.3 seconds.
 File lengths (MBytes):  RWF=   1358 Int=      0 D2E=      0 Chk=      2 Scr=      1
 Normal termination of Gaussian 16 at Mon Jun  3 14:39:50 2024.

Now there is a keyword called Dipole with entries Dipole=0.,0.,-0.7329466 which I converted to Debye, equals to the 1.8630 as shown in total Dipole.
So, my question is, what does the keyword Density=Current does? Does it takes into account the CCSD density rather than SCF to calculate the dipole moment?
In many questions, this keyword is used to obtain the excited state density. However, I did not find where the ground state density can also be found by this.

'Use the density matrix for the current method. This is the default when no option is given to Density.' source: https://gaussian.com/density/

If in doubt, you can do an independent check by calculating the dipole moment as the first derivative of the energy wrt. to a linear external electric field. In this case, use field=z10 and field=-z10, and use the CCSD energies to do a numerical differentiation.

In your first example, the dipole moment has been calculated from the SCF density, not the CCSD density.
This behaviour is (probably) counter intuitive, but it is explained in the Gaussian manual:

By default, population and other analysis procedures use the SCF density (i.e., the Hartree-Fock density for post-SCF methods; the DFT density for DFT jobs, and the CASSCF density for CAS jobs)...

Note that this behaviour is different to specifying just the Density keyword without any options:

Current
Use the density matrix for the current method. This is the default when no option is given to Density.

This means that Density and Density=Current are synonymous, and either will use the density appropriate for the method chosen (this is normally what you want). Not specifying any Density option at all will instead always default to the SCF density (the same as writing Density=SCF).
It's hard to say exactly why this behaviour was chosen, but it's probably because densities aren't available for some methods (while SCF always is). Some high-level MP (MP5? some MP4?) are excluded I believe.
